# Cannot edit particular user data using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii framework. I am doing update operation using yii framework. I have controller with name sitecontroller.php, model jobseekerprofile.php, view personal.php. My table is job_seeker_profile with fields id,user_id,contact_no,gender,dob,mstatus,address.I can't update data by form posting.

My controller is **sitecontroller.php**

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionpersonal()
    {
        $user_id = trim($_GET['id']);
        $model = new jobseekerprofile();
        $model = jobseekerprofile::model()->find(array(
            'select' => 'contact_no,address', "condition" => "user_id=$user_id",
            'limit' => 1,));
        $model = $this->loadModel($user_id);
        if (isset($_POST['jobseekerprofile'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['jobseekerprofile'];
            if ($model->save()) {
                $this->redirect(array('profile', 'user_id' => $model->user_id));
            }
        }
        $this->render('personal', array('model' => $model));
    }

    public function loadModel($user_id)
    {
        echo $model = jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($user_id);
        if ($model === null)
            throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }
}
```

**view-personal.php**

```
    <div class="form">
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(),
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true
    ),
)); ?>
<?php
foreach (Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
}
?>
    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'Contact No'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'contact_no'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'contact_no'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'Address'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'address'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'address'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
    </div>


<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

**model-jobseekerprofile.php**

```
 rules in model


public function rules()
  {
    return array(
                array('contact_no,gender,dob,address,mstatus','required'),
    );
 }
```

Anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use uppercases.

Jobseekerprofile.php and `$model = new Jobseekerprofile();` at least, I'd even call it: JobseekerProfile.php and `$model = new JobseekerProfile();` or something.

Example controller (not tested):

```
public function actionPersonal($id) {
    $model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($id);

    if (isset($_POST['Jobseekerprofile'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Jobseekerprofile'];
        if ($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
    }

    $this->render('personal', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Also you could use the [Gii posibilities of Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) for these standard forms. It will generate forms based on your database and the relations in it.